# fontawesome doesn't work only in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-awesome

**Problem.**

Only Internet Explorer browser doesn't display font-awesome icon.

Funny thing is it's been working until yesterday.
[This is a link, check this out.](http://geniusdm.azurewebsites.net/Home/Problem)

Try the link above with IE, then there will be a white, thick horizontal line, which is supposed to include an **"?"** icon in the middle.

Try it again with Chrome, FireFox, Safari and anything, then **"?"** icon will appear in the middle of the line.

**More info**

I'm hosting this website on Microsoft Azure. It's free mode by the way.

There's no additional configuration for MIME type. This web is based on MVC5.

Strangely enough, CSS properties on `:after` persudo are all canceled in IE like there's overridings on the element or something ( which is absolutely not!! ), please inspect it with F12 tool. This is probably a clue for you. ( I completely have no idea of why the properties got canceled )

**What I've done...**

- Setting MIME type manually
- Checking if IE is on compatibility mode or registered as it is.
- Looking at console log, to see if there's an error on any font-related resources.
- Diagnosing with F12 network menu.
- Googling with this issue and finding possible answers in Stackoverflow.

---

What seems to be the matter? It worked until yesterday but today it just doesn't all of sudden. I deleted some codes I added today, making the resources absolutely same as yesterday, but it still doesn't work. It drives me crazy!!

Comment: Local files we cant access.. try to put it on JS bin or other testing sites..

Comment: @GoldPearl Oh my god I'm so sorry, it was a mistake. I changed it please try again.

Answer (score -1):

you must upgrade your font-awesome package and use this in @font-face{}

```
 src: url('../font/font-awesome.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
```

i hope helfpul

Comment: font-awesome.min.css on my website already included it. `src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0') format('embedded-opentype')`

Comment: try this : `src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0') format('embedded-opentype'),`

Comment: Your suggestion is already built in font-awesome.min.css, `font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0') format('woff'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');·····` I've never changed this before.

Comment: this is work fine on my project ... there is no problem in any browser